# AngularJS Scope as HTML attribute value

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, scope

I am trying to use an AngularJS $scope as an HTML attribute rather than viewable text.

main.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp');

myApp.controller("buttonCtrl", ['$scope', function($scope){

$scope.johnny = [
    {quote: 'Anything for My Princess', controller: 'Princess'}
];

}]);
```

page1.html

```
<button ng-repeat="button in johnny" 
    ng-class="dynamic" 
    class="topcoat-button"
    ng-controller="{{button.controller}}"   <---- this is what does not work 
    ng-click="play()">
    {{button.quote}}
</button>
```

How can I fix this so I can add these variables as an attribute value.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS: dynamically assign controller from ng-repeat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944207/angularjs-dynamically-assign-controller-from-ng-repeat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular.js is a bit weird when doing this, but this should work. Also you're using `ng-repeat` wrong, but it's fixed below.

```
<button ng-repeat="johnny in buttons" 
    ng-class="dynamic" 
    class="topcoat-button"
    ng-controller="this.johnny.controller"
    ng-click="play()">
    {{johnny.quote}}
</button>
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for responding. when I put in this.johnny.controller the button I see {{johnny.quote}} instead of the value. Also, I can only see the buttons if johnny is after "in".

Comment: Ah yes, it is buttons in johnny, but I need to use {{button.quote}}; however, ng-controller is not working. I have updated my question so it is correct.

Comment: Ohh, I took out the quotes on Princess and that solved it. Thank you very much for leading me to the answer!