# Dynamically assign ng-controller on runtime

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a situation where I need to dynamically change the controller, so that the scope variables are influenced accordingly. General structure:

```
<div ng-controller="GameController">
   // some general HTML which fits all types of games
    <div ng-controller="someScopeVar"> // Type of game
      // some game-type-specific ng-models that should respond to the change of controller, i.e scope
    </div
</div>
```

I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944207/angularjs-dynamically-assign-controller-from-ng-repeat) that it can be done within an `ng-repeat`. Can it be done outside of it?
In other words, can I tell angular to read it as a variable rather than a string literal?

Comment: I think this question is misleading. Are you really trying to set the controller dynamically, or just change the contents of $scope ?

Comment: `someScopeVar` should be a controller function, what value you use now?

Comment: @Grundy, you were right. I used a string literal for the controller, which was defined outside the scope, rather than assigning the controller itself to `someScopeVal`. Please post as answer

Comment: @Grundy, this works for the initial assignment, but when I try to change it in response to a user click event, it stays as it were

Comment: @ExpertSystem, I am trying to change the scope itself, not the contents of the existing one.

Comment: Why get into all that trouble ? Why not just use an object on $scope and bind to the properties of that object ?

Comment: You should try to *deeply* observe the `ui-router` here are some *(up to date)* links to supper basic resources http://stackoverflow.com/a/20581135/1679310. This feature is in fact a state machine, which is intended to change parts of your app based on state changes (could be dependent on url but does not have to). You will just manage your states, and these could have many inner views with related controllers. Change state - the same view (template) with different controller will be injected... really please, try to observe that ;)

Comment: @Matanya can you provide a bit more markup and js code? or possible fiddle?

Comment: @RadimKöhler, That is a whole new realm I wasn't aware of. Will definitely explore it.

Comment: Great that you do! Really. I am using that almost a year, for simple as well as for complex applications. That is radical change in usage of `angular`, because we can start to think in `states` *(business logic pieces ala menu, nav, main-game section)*... great to see that you at least try. I am *almost* sure that you'll be at the end using it ;) good luck ;) PS: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24690519/1679310 there are links to great blog posts... which will help to understand

Comment: @RadimKöhler, Please consider posting as an answer. I find the new concept of states which are independent of URL to be a comprehensive solution for dynamically handling controllers and views, with ease and elegance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, `angular` has a really powerful *feature/library* for handling these scenarios - [**`ui-router`**](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) *(with its powerful [wiki](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki))*.

The `ui-router` is an answer to need to develop functional pieces - **states**, rather then think in view/url *(cite from a home page)*:

> AngularUI Router is a routing framework for AngularJS, which allows you to organize the parts of your interface into a **state machine**. Unlike the *$route* service in the Angular ngRoute module, which is organized around URL routes, `UI-Router` is organized around **states**, which may optionally have routes, as well as other behavior, attached.

There are some very interesting blog posts:

- [AngularJS State Management with ui-router](http://txt.fliglio.com/2013/05/angularjs-state-management-with-ui-router/) *(by Ben Schwartz)*

> ...The most interesting thing about AngularJS's new router, isn't the router itself, but the state manager that comes with it. Instead of targeting a controller/view to render for a given url, you target a state. States are managed in a heirarchy providing inheritance of parent states and complex composition of page components, all the while remaining declarative in nature...

- [The basics of using ui-router with AngularJS](http://joelhooks.com/blog/2013/07/22/the-basics-of-using-ui-router-with-angularjs/) (by Joel Hooks)

> ...`ui-router` fully embraces the state-machine nature of a routing system. It allows you to **define states**, and **transition** your application to those states. The real win is that it allows you to **decouple nested states**, and do some very complicated layouts in an elegant way.

Exactly the point we need - decouple child states... **dynamically change the controller in fact** ... could be by url change or just a state change *(one sibling child instead of other without url change)*

> You need to think about your routing a bit differently, but once you get your head around the state-based approach, I think you will like it...

Finally, there are few links, which I would mark as the saint grail of ui-router

- [Sample application](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/#/). In action we can see, how the ui-router state machine does work. We can load *list* as a **parent state**, then we can select row items, which do represent their own **child state**... while parent is not reloading *([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20558850/1679310) I tried to explain it in more details)*
- [**`state.js`**](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/master/sample/app/contacts/contacts.js) - the essential piece of code of the sample application. This is one of the best documented code snippets I've seen... Spent some time to go through and this will give you the 80% percent of answers: How `ui-Router` is working

From my experience, this is really suitable for small apps as well as for large scale systems... love it...

Answer (score 2):

The way this works for `ngRepeat` is different. It works because it compiles each repetition, which is what you need to do here.

For example:

```
mainCtrl = function($scope, $compile, $element) {
    $scope.someScopeVar = ctrl1;
    $scope.changeCtrl = function(id) {
        $scope.someScopeVar = id === 1 ? ctrl1 : ctrl2;
        var elm = $element.find('div');
        elm.replaceWith($compile(template)($scope));
    }
}

var ctrl1 = function($scope) { 
  $scope.name = 'World';
}

var ctrl2 = function($scope) {      
  $scope.name = 'John';
}
```

We assign each controller function to `$scope.someScopeVar`, then we must compile a new element with the new controller and replace the old one.

I don't believe angular has the capability to update a controller on the fly like that. Might be a good idea for a new feature.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/75aHL)

---

Another option would be to use the mixin pattern to update the main scope. You don't get a new shiny scope but it may work for your purposes.

```
mainCtrl = function($scope, $compile, $element) {
    angular.extend($scope, ctrl1());
    $scope.changeCtrl = function(id) {
         angular.extend($scope, id === 1 ? ctrl1() : ctrl2());
    }
}

var ctrl1 = function() { 
  var obj = {};
  obj.name = 'World';
  return obj;
}

var ctrl2 = function() {      
  var obj = {};
  obj.name = 'John';
  return obj;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/75aHL/1)