# how to define multiple ng-view in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I am new in angular js, i want create a app using multiple ngview please help me

**Index.html**

```
<html ng-app="firstGenApp">
<body>
<div >
    <ng-view></ng-view>
</div>
</body>
```

1)here i include login.html while loading index.html

**Login.html**

```
<h1>Login Page</h1>
<form ng-submit="login(userName, userPass)" ng-controller="LoginCtrl" class="ng-scope ng-pristine ng-valid">
    <label>User name</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="userName" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="password" ng-model="userPass" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
    <br/>
        {{loginError}}  {{loggedUser}}
    <br/><br/>
    <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="">Login</button>
    <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
</form>
```

2)after login success i am including homepage.html

**Homepage.html**

```
<div ng-view></div>
```

3) while including homepage.html its giving error

4) This homepage.html having one ng-view i want use this ng-view after including abc.html etc..
please help me how to use multiple ng-view ?

Comment: Just a hint. There is already a library solving the issue with many views: the angular js `ui-router`. Try to observe it https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki. Here I tried to put some other links together... http://stackoverflow.com/a/24693129/1679310 ... I would say that this could save lot of coding for you ... just a suggestion ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can have only one `ng-view` per angularjs application.

You can change its content in several ways: `ng-include`, `ng-switch` or mapping different controllers and templates through the `$routeProvider`.

If you want to have nested views, or multiple parallel views, then you definitely want to try **UI-Router** : https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router