# AngularJS: ng-app inside ng-include

Tags: angularjs

I have a template like this.

```
<body ng-app="demo" ng-controller="demo">
  <div ng-include="/main.html">
  </div>
</body>
```

And the main.html is.

```
<div ng-app="main" ng-controller="main>
  ""
</div>
```

here is the js.

**JS-1**

```
var myapp = angular.module('demo', []);
myapp.controller('demo', function($scope,$routeParams, $route,$http) {
$scope.variable="444"
})
```

**JS-2**

```
var mainapp = angular.module('mainapp', []);
myapp.controller('main', function($scope,$routeParams, $route,$http) {

})
```

Is it possible to access the scope of JS-1 inside JS-2?, if yes how, if no is there any solution to this.Thanks.

Comment: If you don't mind, I would suggest to you to take some time and observe the ui-router: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki , there are som links explaining it more http://stackoverflow.com/a/24693129/1679310... from my pespective - this awsome state machine library for angular could do a lot for you...

Comment: Why dont you try service?

Answer (score 1):

It depend what you want to do. 
If you want read $scope.variable variable from JS-1, you should see it in JS-2 $scope. 
If you want modify $scope.variable form JS-1, you should create method in JS-1:

```
$scope.changes = function(data){
        $scope.variable = data;
}
```

This method also should be available in JS-2 $scope.

This isn't nice solution but should work.
The best solution is to create service which will provide operations on JS-1 fields.