# Dynamic controller change in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, controller, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need to dynamically change controller of one particular div by clicking some input buttons.

Why it works the first way, but doesn't work the second way if I replace one-element array by controller itself (see code below).

And how to implement such functionality in a better way?

---

[Plnkr with one-element array (works)](http://plnkr.co/edit/AjbwnqODzA3K5uFnrl9Q)

**index.html**

```html
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    Hello, {{name}}!
    <input type="button" value="click me" ng-click="changeCtrl(0)"/>
    <input type="button" value="click me" ng-click="changeCtrl(1)"/>
    <input type="button" value="click me" ng-click="changeCtrl(2)"/>

    <div ng-repeat = "ctrl in curCtrl" ng-controller="ctrl">
        {{ blah }}
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller("MyCtrl", MyCtrl);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Username';

    $scope.ctrls = [ctrlA, ctrlB, ctrlC];
    $scope.curCtrl = [ctrlA];

    $scope.changeCtrl = function (idx) {
        $scope.curCtrl = [$scope.ctrls[idx]];
    }
}

function ctrlA($scope) {$scope.blah = "One";}
function ctrlB($scope) {$scope.blah = "Two";}
function ctrlC($scope) {$scope.blah = "Three";}
```

---

[Plnkr with controller instead (doesn't work)](http://plnkr.co/edit/v1Ubofk1mH4lFEJXsX3o)

**index.html**

```html
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    Hello, {{name}}!
    <input type="button" value="click me" ng-click="changeCtrl(0)"/>
    <input type="button" value="click me" ng-click="changeCtrl(1)"/>
    <input type="button" value="click me" ng-click="changeCtrl(2)"/>

    <div ng-controller="curCtrl">
        {{ blah }}
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller("MyCtrl", MyCtrl);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'Username';

  $scope.ctrls = [ctrlA, ctrlB, ctrlC];
  $scope.curCtrl = ctrlA;

  $scope.changeCtrl = function(idx) {
    $scope.curCtrl = $scope.ctrls[idx];
  }
}

function ctrlA($scope) {$scope.blah = "One";}
function ctrlB($scope) {$scope.blah = "Two";}
function ctrlC($scope) {$scope.blah = "Three";}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works with `ng-repeat` because `ng-repeat` destroys and re-compiles the HTML when the array reference changes. You would have to compile manually if you want the same result without an array, using the `$compile` service on the `$element`. It could be done in your controller, but a directive might be better.

You may also want to take advantage of client-side routing to accomplish this (ui-router allows nested states).

Check out these answers:

[Dynamic NG-Controller Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24762229/dynamic-ng-controller-name)

[Dynamically assign ng-controller on runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24639491/dynamically-assign-ng-controller-on-runtime)

Otherwise, you could use a quick hack with `ng-if` and `$timeout`:

```
$scope.changeCtrl = function(idx) {
    // ng-if sees null and destroys the HTML

    $scope.curCtrl = null;

    $timeout(function() { 
      // ng-if sees a new object and re-compiles the HTML

      $scope.curCtrl = $scope.ctrls[idx];
    });
}

<div ng-if="curCtrl" ng-controller="curCtrl">
    {{ blah }}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just wanted to make sure that angular doesn't watch for controller changes in both cases. I was confused by the fact that it worked with ng-repeat by one-element array, but you made it clear for me now. Thanks.