# AngularJS dynamically injecting controller, class etc

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, controller, widget

I have a widgets list that is built dynamically.
Each widget is represented by html, class, controller and a name. Some of those might be empty (not all widgets require a controller for example).
Then I use Gridster to load those widgets dynamically into `<li>`.

My basic intuition was to ngRepeat those `<li>`s but the `Controller` can't be loaded dynamically from a scope variable.
I saw various suggestions [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944207/angularjs-dynamically-assign-controller-from-ng-repeat)
But I can't fit them into my own code for the following reasons:

1. The controllers I use don't sit inside the main controller, those controllers may be used in different places
2. The widgets are created dynamically per user request. Ofcourse I don't let the user choose the html/class/controller to use, those are predefined but he might use some widgets and and he might not.

Perhaps one of those suggestions works for me and I just can't see it, so will appreciate guidance. Here is the relevant code:

**Html:**

```
<div class="widgets-background" ng-controller="Investigation2Ctrl" data-ng-init="refetchData();toggleCollapse();initWidgets();">
    <div id="widgets" class="gridster">
        <ul>
            <li data-row="1" data-col="1" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1" class="yellow" name="Updates Widget">
                <p style="white-space: pre;">{{gridsterUpdates}}</p>
            </li>
            <li ng-repeat="widget in widgetsList" name="widget.name" data-row="1" data-col="2" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1">
                <div ng-class="widget.widgetClass" ng-include="widget.widgetHtmlInclude" ng-controller="widget.widgetController"></div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function Investigation2Ctrl($scope, $http, $dialog, DialogService, Config, ApplicationContextService, CaseHierarchyService, GeoService, Logger, $timeout) {

    $scope.widgetsList = [];
    $scope.initWidgets = function() {
        $scope.addWidget('Export Widget', 'partials/investigation/widgets/widget-export.html');
        $scope.addWidget('Timeline Widget', 'partials/investigation/widgets/widget-timeline.html');
        $scope.addWidget('Search Widget', 'partials/investigation/widgets/widget-search.html');
        $scope.addWidget('Facets  Widget', 'partials/investigation/widgets/widget-facets.html', 'FacetsCtrl');
    };

    $scope.addWidget = function(widgetName, widgetIncludeHtml, widgetController, widgetClass) {
        widgetClass = typeof widgetClass !== 'undefined' ? widgetClass : 'widget-container';
        $scope.widgetsList.push({
            'widgetName': widgetName || '',
            'widgetIncludeHtml': widgetIncludeHtml || '',
            'widgetController': widgetController || '',
            'widgetClass': widgetClass || ''
        });
    };
}
```

Obviously the error I'm getting is `widget.widgetController is undefined`, which makes since since he tries to load a controller called `widget.widgetController`

The only option I thought about is creating the `<li><div ng-include...` html in JavaScript dynamically and injecting it, but well, it sucks.

Answer (score 0):

Create a dummy, empty function and use it as controller.

```
function dummyCtrl() {} // register as controller if required.

widgetController: widgetController ||'dummyCtrl'
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit why is this working and where exactly to put it in regards of my code?

Are you trying to solve a scenario where the controller is not needed? Since thats not the issue, ng-controller = ' ' is fine..

Comment: Can yo create a plunker/fiddle for this?