# AngularJS - how do you associate a controller by path after compiling the html?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-template, angular-controller

Is it possible to dynamically associate a controller, after it has been compiled from a template?

```
//Controller /path/ctrl/MainCtrl.js
angular.module('app')
    .controller('MainCtrl', function () {

    });

//Directive  /path/dir/myDir.js
function link(scope, element, attrs) {
    $templateRequest('path/oneTpl.tpl').then(function (html) {
        $compile(element.html(html).contents())(scope);
        //How can I do to dynamically inject MainCtrl into the oneTpl.tpl template using the path (/path/ctrl/MainCtrl.js)?
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add an attribute to your compiled template (would be good to know, what you template is exactly).

Try following code:

```
element.setAttribute(name, value);
```

Example:

```
<button>Hello World</button>
var b = document.querySelector("button"); 

b.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
```

So you just need a identifier of your template, e.g. id or class an then set your Attribute.

JQuery: `$('#yourTemplate').setAttribute('ng-controller','yourController' );`

If this doesn't help you, maybe following threads will help you:

[AngularJS: dynamically assign controller from ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944207/angularjs-dynamically-assign-controller-from-ng-repeat)

[Dynamic NG-Controller Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24762229/dynamic-ng-controller-name)

[Dynamically assign ng-controller on runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24639491/dynamically-assign-ng-controller-on-runtime)